# Replacing tag without losing inner tags in JavaScript

Tags: appendchild, replacewith, clonenode

Let suppose I have this HTML code :

```
<div id="actual">
        <ol>
          <li>robots</li>
          <li>wrong</li>
          <li>hi</li>
          <li>bye</li>
        </ol>
      </div>
```

i want to replace ol by ul without losing the inner tags (li)and thier content

i tried that:

```
        const actual = document.getElementById('actual');
        const ulReplace = document.createElement('ul');
        actual.children[0].replaceWith(ulReplace);
```

but i replace the ol by ul and remove every thing inside it.

also i try to clone the content and re-append it after but also i lose it when removed

Comment: Here might be the answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61115938/javascript-regex-to-replace-ul-or-ol-with-only-text-within-li-tag

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript regex to replace <ul> or <ol> with only text within <li> tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61115938/javascript-regex-to-replace-ul-or-ol-with-only-text-within-li-tag)